# How to check the duplicate characters from string2 in string1 and then remove it?

Tags: c#

```
e.g String1 = "Hello";
e.g String2 = "eo";
```

I want to remove all chars in string1 that are in string2.
So the output should be `"Hll"`

Comment: You want string "Hll" as result, I understand correctly?

Comment: Someone get a medic, quick! leaner was taken down before s/he could finish the question.

Comment: Is this a real question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most efficient but a very readable solution:

```
string input = "hello";
string dupes = "eo";

var output = new string((from c in input where !dupes.Contains(c) select c).ToArray());
```

A more efficient approach for large strings would be using a `Hashset<char>` for the dupes:

```
string input = "hello";
string dupes = "eo";

HashSet<char> dupeSet = new HashSet<char>();
foreach (char c in dupes)
    dupeSet.Add(c);

var output = new string(input.Where(c => !dupeSet.Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you could do it using LINQ like this:

```
new string(string1.Where(c => !string2.Contains(c)).ToArray())
```

For your examples, this returns `"Hll"`.

If you want to get a collection of all characters from `string1` that are not in `string2`, that's even simpler:

```
string1.Except(string2)
```

Comment: giving you a plus for showing the shortest code :) `string1.Except(string2)`

Comment: string1.Except(string2)
 throws an exception

Comment: What kind of exception? What are the values of the strings?

Comment: System.Linq.Enumerable+<ExceptIterator>d__99

Comment: I was asking about the values of the strings, not what the return value was. And you still didn't say what the exception was.

Comment: string input = "hello";
string dupes = "eo";

Comment: `"hello".Except("eo")` works fine. I guess the problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: public static string RemoveDuplicates2(string str1, string dupes)
        {
            var result = str1.Except(dupes);
            return result.ToString();
        }                                         
//Method call           Console.WriteLine(StringDuplicates.RemoveDuplicates2("hello", "eo"));

Comment: Yeah, that will result in the string like you posted. But it will not throw an exception. To get the proper string, you can use `string.Concat(str1.Except(dupes))`.

Comment: System.Linq.Enumerable+<ExceptIterator>d__99`1[System.Char]

Answer (score 0):

A classic approach (without LINQ) is:

```
string String1 = "Hello", String2 = "eo";

for (int i = 0; i < String2.Length; i++)
{
    String1 = String1.Replace(String[i] + "", ""); // replace them with empty string
}
```

The result is:

```
String1 = "Hll"
```

Comment: What's the point of having `if-else` at all? You could just change the condition to `!= -1` and just have the `if` block.

Comment: Why check IndexOf of instead of just calling Replace always? Is it to increase performance or is there another reason? Could there be situations where this extra check might make the code run *slower* instead of faster?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ I know :) I am trying to simplifying the code for him

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = new string(string1.Where(x => !string2.Contains(x)).ToArray());
```

result:

```
string1 = "Hll"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = String.Join("", String1.Split(String2.ToCharArray()));
```

It might not be efficient, but it is a solution for small strings.

Answer (score -2):

```
    string string1 = "hello";
    string string2 = "eo";

    string1 = Regex.Replace(string1, "[" + string2 + "]", "");
```

Comment: This won't work correctly if `string2` contains some special characters, like `]`, `^` or `-`.

Comment: well, it will work for alphanumeric characters.. just not special characters as svick pointed out